# how to change default background of iframe body that loads a PDF

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a PDF in an `iframe` in Chrome.  The PDF is on the same server the page is on.  When the `iframe` loads, it brings with it a default background color on the `body` element.  I want to change this default, or change it on the fly.  I've tried, but I think what's going on is that when I try to change it it's not there yet (because the PDF hasn't loaded yet).  Any way to do this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/XJcr5/2/

```
<p id="btn">load PDF</p>
<iframe style="display:none;">


$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('iframe').attr('src','http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsFiddle.pdf');
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('iframe').show();
});
```

Comment: What you've got now works for me on Win7/Chrome --- or are you meaning you want to change the background of the PDF itself???

Comment: no, the background color of the body element of the iframe.  on my example, click 'load PDF', then inspect element of the iframe.  you'll see the background color of the body is set to rgb(38,38,38).

Comment: interestingly it's the same on safari

Comment: I get a flash of whatever color I change the body background to - but after that, I can't seem to change it using that method. Even if I set a timeout so the PDF has definitely loaded. I imagine it's being set by the PDF embed plugin.
Can you write the `<embed>` in the iframe and load the PDF into there, instead of the whole iframe?